# custom snippets to surround a selected code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a javascript project using VS Code there is a feature which surrounds the code with a snippets
like below

[image]

is there a way to add a custom surround snippet

for example, this is my code

```
`<td>${x.debit}</td>`
```

and I want to Surround it with parseFloat(MYCODE).toFixed(2)

```
`<td>${parseFloat(x.debit).toFixed(2)}</td>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yatki.vscode-surround). The setting needed is something like the following added to your `settings.json`:

```json
"surround.custom": {
  "toFixed2": {
    "label": "tf2",
    "description": "Some description that will show in the picker",
    "snippet": "parseFloat($TM_SELECTED_TEXT).toFixed(2)",
    "languageIds": [
      "javascript"
    ]
  }
}
```

You don't have to include `"languageIds"` but it's useful to limit when these are available; `"description"` is not mandatory either.

A bit of limitation is that for this to work, you'd need a specific selection (let's denote it by `[` and `]`) as opposed to having the whole string selected:

```
`<td>${[x.debit]}</td>`
```

From there you invoke the command `surround.with` (might be useful to bind it to a key combintion) and look for `tf2`. Of course you can change the label to what makes more sense to you. The `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT` seems to be hardcoded and used to pick up the selected text. You can also tweak the snippet like this:

```json
"snippet": "parseFloat($TM_SELECTED_TEXT).toFixed(2$0)"
```

The `$0` token denotes where the caret will be after you finish your input, and placing it right after the `2` might be useful if you want to quickly change the number of decimal places for example.